# How to test if application is running, and pass a variable from the terminal

Tags: applescript

Could anyone please give me a hand to debug my attempt to pass a variable to an applescript and test whether a different application is presently running.

For `emacsclient` to work properly, the Emacs GUI server needs to be running -- first I want to verify Emacs GUI is running [`(server-start)` is already in my `init.el` file] -- if so, then bring to foreground (focus) with no delay before proceeding to launch `emacsclient` -- else, launch Emacs GUI and wait a second for the server to start up.  Then, run `emacsclient` to open the named file.  From terminal, I'd like to type:

```
osascript script-name variable-file-name
```

**script error: The run handler is specified more than once, or there were top-level commands in addition to the run handler. (-2752)**

```
on is_running(appName)
  tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running
set EmacsRunning to is_running("Emacs")
if EmacsRunning then
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
else
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
  delay 1
end if

on run arg
  do shell script "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient arg"
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
on run argv

    set argvApp to application (argv as text) --Coerce list to text
    set appIsRunning to argvApp is running

    if appIsRunning then
        beep 1
        --insert your code
    else
        beep 2
        --insert your code
    end if

    (*
        tell application "SystemUIServer"
            activate
            display dialog appIsRunning
        end tell
    *)
end run
```